# Android SQLite with ContentProvider and BaaS

Tags: android, sqlite, parse-platform, firebase, android-contentprovider

Can BaaS solutions such as Firebase and Parse be used with an already existing SQLite database locally, and interfaced via a ContentProvider that was already configured?

I could only find information so far on using each solution's proprietary local storage solution. However, if I just treat the BaaS as a REST API, is that a feasible solution?

I'm interested in using a BaaS at this time for my first app for data synchronization/user authentication across devices, and eventually learning how to set up my own server for projects thereafter.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am moving from Parse to Firebase.

In the Parse world, I am able to use the best of both BaaS and Content Providers. Had the BaaS invoked in the Sync Adapter calls, refreshed the local SQLite DB and which in turn updated the CursorAdapter via Content Providers.

In the Firebase world, there is no need for any additional Sync Adapters and hence having a local Content Provider and SQLite is redundant. Yeah, still I could have all of them play together, but not needed as Firebase has the ability to directly update the view.